# Pandas create a mask based on multiple thresholds

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

##### Problem:

Lets say there is a Pandas Dataframe:

```py
d = {'A': [0.1, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2],
     'B': [0.7, 0.3, 0.2, 0.9],
     'Z': [0.5, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6],
     'sth': ['abc', 'something', 'unimportant', 'x']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
df
```

|  | A | B | Z | sth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.1 | 0.7 | 0.5 | "abc" |
| 1 | 0.4 | 0.3 | 0.3 | "something" |
| 2 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.4 | "unimportant" |
| 3 | 0.2 | 0.9 | 0.6 | "x" |

```
thresholds = {'A': 0.5, 'B':0.8, 'Z': 0.3}
```

**I want to find a mask that will have `True` for *each row*, where highest value of this row is lower than threshold defined for this class.**

For the given example, correct mask would be:

```
[ True, True, False, False]
```

##### Explanation:

0. Row `0`. First find the highest value in this row `max([0.1,0.7,0.5]) = 0.7`. Note that `0.7` was in column `B`. Compare this value with the threshold (0.8) for column `B`. `0.8 > 0.7`, so result is True.
1. Row `1` has highest value at column `A` cause `max([0.4,0.3,0.3]) = 0.4`, and threshold for class `A` is 0.5, hence `True`
2. Row `2` has highest value at column `Z` cause `max([0.2,0.2,0.4]) = 0.4`, and threshold for class `Z` is 0.3, hence `False`
3. Row `3` has highest value at column `B` cause `max([0.2,0.9,0.6]) = 0.9`, and threshold for class `B` is 0.8. Cause `0.8 < 0.9` this row is `False`

Comment: In you're example data, Row 0, has a Z  value of `0.5`, wouldn't that be above the threshold and make example `[ False, True, False]`

Comment: Good point. no, because I analise each row, not each column. I see phrasing of my question could have been a little bit confusing. ;S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `apply` with a `lambda` function to calculate the ones that breach the threshold.

Try this:

```
def within_threshold(x, thresh):
    key = pd.to_numeric(x[thresh.keys()]).idxmax(axis=0)
    return x[key] > thresh[key]

df["within_threshold"] = df.apply(lambda x: within_threshold(x, thresholds), axis=1)
df
```

The full code snippet:

```
import pandas as pd

thresholds = {'A': 0.5, 'B':0.8, 'Z': 0.3}

d = {'A': [0.1,0.4,0.2],'B':[0.7,0.3,0.2],'Z':[0.5,0.3,0.4],'sth':["a","b","c"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

def within_threshold(x, thresh):
    key = pd.to_numeric(x[thresh.keys()]).idxmax(axis=0)
    return x[key] > thresh[key]

df["within_threshold"] = df.apply(lambda x: within_threshold(x, thresholds), axis=1)
df
```

Should get you this:

```
    A   B   Z   sth within_threshold
0   0.1 0.7 0.5 a   True
1   0.4 0.3 0.3 b   True
2   0.2 0.2 0.4 c   False
3   0.2 0.9 0.2 d   False
```

*Also, from your example data, `row 0` has a Z value of `0.5`, which is above the Z threshold.*

#### Edit by OP

This answer lead me to find the solution, so I edited it, and it now solves the problem.

Comment: I see I didn't include a comprehensive example. I fixed it now. In row 0, you only look at the highest value (0.7), and then compare it to the threshold of said class (here B).

Comment: The line `key = x[thresh.keys()].idxmax(axis=0)` throws an error.  `TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype` when I run it. I think we could further reduce the example by removing the `if` and just returning the expression. I added `pd.to_numeric(...` to fix the error.

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension can do the work straightforwards :

```
[df[col].max < tresholds[col] for col in tresholds.keys()]
```

However, I wouldn't use a list to get the result but rather a dictionary with key being the column name and the value the desired boolean. Indexing with integers could be a bit ambiguous depending on the dataframe you are using.